# Does apt-get install depend on kernel version of the operating system (OS) or the distribution of OS?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, installation, apt-get, package-managers

I have a new VM freshly installed with ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The default kernel version is 4.4.0. If i do

```
sudo apt-get install criu
```

It will install criu appropriate for the kernel version 4.4.0 and ubuntu distribution version 16.04. But what will happen if i upgrade the kernel to 4.10.0? My question is: if I upgrade the kernel to a higher version (4.10.0) from default version (4.4.0) in ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I try to do

```
sudo apt-get install ldx
```

Will it install ldx for 4.10.0 kernel or 4.4.0 kernel and Why?
Will this install also depend on the ubuntu distribution version? Or, does the install only depend on the distribution version?
Kindly explain. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This question should be asked on/migrated to unix.stackexchange.com

Userspace usually applications don't depend on specific kernel versions.
nothing happens if you upgrade. it won't upgrade other packages that don't depend on specific kernel versions.

the reason is that the ABI of the kernel doesn't change that much and applications don't need to control the kernel verision beyond a certain level
like LINUX > 2.6

Some applications like networking software, device drivers, ... depend on specific kernel features and try to solve this in a few different ways:

1. dkms: they ship with the source code for the device drivers that they need, every time a kernel is installed/removed the drivers are compiled against it automatically
2. They ship their own kernel and/or binary blobs: android is an example, you can't have video if you use a pristine kernel
3. patch: They ship diff files to apply to the kernel source before compiling. nvidia used to do this and blobs and dkms at the same time; they literally got the middle finger for it; no one else does it since.
4. there are more ways that i can't think of right now.

If you want to read further on how apt decides what to install I highly recommend the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(Debian) and looking up what each configuration file does.